# Laravel filled vs sometimes

Tags: laravel

I have a validation case where if a value is present the validate it as boolean otherwise skip it.

My thinking is to use `sometimes` rule like:

```
return[
  'my_filed'=>'sometimes|boolean'
];
```

Question whats the difference between 'filled' and `sometimes` ?

Answer (score 4):

**Sometimes**

> In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the input array. To quickly accomplish this, add the sometimes rule to your rule list

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

`sometimes` means, only apply the rest of the validation rules if the field shows up in the request. Imagine `sometimes` is like an if statement that checks if the field is present in the request/input before applying any of the rules.

**Filled**

The field under validation must not be empty when it is present. So `filled` means if the field is there in an array it should have some value like `required`.

Comment: In other words `filled` behaves in the same way as `sometimes|required`.